# Error lookup for key [LANGUAGES] usin i118n

Tags: django, internationalization

I'm having a hard time to make i118 work. When calling my html I get:

```
Failed lookup for key [LANGUAGES] in u"[{'projects': [<Project: etwas>]}]"
```

This was my work flow:

```
#setting.py
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de'

ugettext = lambda s: s

LANGUAGES = (
   ('de', ugettext('German')),
   ('en', ugettext('English')),
   ('pt', ugettext('Portuges')),
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    #...

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
)


#base.html
{% load i18n %}
<html>
<body>
<form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post"> 
{% csrf_token %}
<input name="next" type="hidden" value="next/page" /> 
<select name="language"> 
{% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
{% for language in languages %}
    <option value="{{ language.code }}">{{ language.name_local }}  ({{ language.code }})</option>
{% endfor %}

#projects.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load i18n %} 
{% block content %}
{% for p in projects %}
    <h1>{{ p.title_en }}</h1>
    <p>{{ p.body_de }} </p>
    <p>{{ p.body_pt }} </p>
    <hr>    
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

What am I missing? I can't find any useful information on the error message online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not using [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext).

Comment: Damn, I knew I had to. Forgot to for my test view. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `'django.core.context_processors.i18n'` is not called correctly.

This maybe because your view uses `django.shorcuts.render_to_response` without `context_instance=template.RequestContext(request)`.

A solution is to switch to [`django.shortcuts.render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render).